# Intersecting sets such that the result is a set of sets with collectively unique elements

Tags: algorithm, set

Let's say I have the following sets:

```
X -> {1, 2, 3}  
Y -> {1, 4, 7}  
Z -> {1, 4, 5}
```

I'm looking to find the combination of intersections that produce a number of sets where each element is unique among them all. (Really a set of hashs where each element refers back to the sets it intersects):

```
A -> {2, 3}: {X}
B -> {7}:    {Y}
C -> {5}:    {Z}
D -> {4}:    {Y, Z}
E -> {1}:    {X, Y, Z}
```

Boiling the problem down, following conditions have to be met:

- For each initial set, each element will be in a resulting set created by the intersection of the maximum number of initial sets
- Meaning, each element in an initial set needs to be in exactly one resulting set
- The sets are realistically infinite, meaning stepping through all valid elements isn't feasible, but set operations are fine
- All resulting sets containing no elements can be disregarded

The brute force approach is to loop over the powerset of the initial set in reverse order, intersect each set, then find the difference of this resulting set and all other intersections tested:

```
resulting_sets = {}
for sets in powerset(S):
  s = intersection(sets)
  for rs in resulting_sets.keys():
    s -= rs

  if not s.empty():
    resulting_sets[s] = sets # realistically some kind of reference to sets
```

Of course the above is pretty inefficient at <s>O(n^2log(n))</s> O(2^n * 2^(n/2)) of set operations (and for my purposes it may run up to n^2 times already). Is there a better solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: not iterating any set, only uses set operations

This algorithm is building the result sets constructively, i.e. we modify the existing unique element sets and/or add new ones everytime we see a new source set.

The idea is that, every new set can be split into two parts, one with values already seen, and one with new unique values. For the first part, it is further split into various subsets (up to # of powerset of seen source sets) by the current result sets. For each such subset, it also splits into two parts, one intersects with the new source set, and the other does not. The job is to update the result sets for each of these categories.

For complexity in terms of set operations, this should be O(n*2^n). For the solution posted by the OP, I think the complexity should be O(2^(2n)), because `len(resulting_sets)` has up to 2^n elements in the worst case.

```
def solution(sets):
    result_sets = [] # list of (unique element set, membership) tuples
    for sid, s in enumerate(sets):
        new_sets = []
        for unique_elements, membership in result_sets:
            # The intersect part has wider membership, while the other part
            # has less unique elements (maybe empty).
            # Wider membership must have not been seen before, so add as new.
            intersect = unique_elements & s
            # Special case if all unique elements exist in s, then update
            # in place
            if len(intersect) == len(unique_elements):
                membership.append(sid)
            elif len(intersect) != 0:
                unique_elements -= intersect
                new_sets.append((intersect, membership + [sid]))
            s -= intersect
            if len(s) == 0:
                break
        # Special syntax for Python: there are remaining elements in s
        # This is the part of unseen elements: add as a new result set
        else:
            new_sets.append((s, [sid]))
        result_sets.extend(new_sets)
    print(result_sets)

sets = [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 5}]
solution(sets)

# output:
# [(set([2, 3]), [0]), (set([1]), [0, 1, 2]), (set([7]), [1]), (set([4]), [1, 2]), (set([5]), [2])]
```

--------------- original answer below ---------------

The idea is to find the "membership" of each unique element, i.e. what sets does it belong to. Then we create a dictionary to group all element by their membership, generating the requested sets. The complexity is O(n*len(sets)), or O(n^2) in the worst case.

```
def solution(sets):
    union = set().union(*sets)
    numSets = len(sets)
    numElements = len(union)
    memberships = {}
    for e in union:
        membership = tuple(i for i, s in enumerate(sets) if e in s)
        if membership not in memberships:
            memberships[membership] = []
        memberships[membership].append(e)
    print(memberships)

sets = [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 5}]
solution(sets)

# output:
# {(0, 1, 2): [1], (1, 2): [4], (0,): [2, 3], (1,): [7], (2,): [5]}
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I can't realistically loop over each element. The sets themselves contain upwards of ~2^64 elements and keep track of it through exclusion sets and ranges of elements, not each individual element. One of the bullet points states the constraint

Comment: @Lindenk Are you calculating complexity in terms of # of set operations? Be aware that set intersection is O(min(M,N)) while membership test is O(1) in terms of # of elements.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. For some reason I assumed a powerset was n^2 when it's actually 2^n. Wow that's much worse